# Multiple checkboxes in a single row in gwt cell table

Tags: java, gwt

I have created a cell table with checkbox cell in each column. But when i click on any cell, all check boxes are getting selected. My actual requirement is i want to create child parent relationship in checkbox cells in a row i. e. first column will have checkbox and second column will have its multiple children checkboxes and third will have children for each checkbox from second column. I want to select all children on parent selection and if any child gets unselected parent also should get unselected. Parent will remain selected only if its all children are selected.

Please give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Code is as follows

```
final SelectionModel<ContactInfo> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<ContactInfo>();
    cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel,
            DefaultSelectionEventManager.<ContactInfo> createCheckboxManager(0)); 
    Column<ContactInfo, Boolean> checkColumn = new Column<ContactInfo, Boolean>(new NamedCheckBoxCell(true, false)) {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(ContactInfo object) {
            NamedCheckBoxCell namedCell = (NamedCheckBoxCell)this.getCell();
            namedCell.setTextValue(object.getFirstName());
            return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
        }
    };
    cellTable.addColumn(checkColumn, SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("First Name"));
    cellTable.setColumnWidth(checkColumn, 20, Unit.PCT);

    cellTable.addCellPreviewHandler(DefaultSelectionEventManager.<ContactInfo> createCheckboxManager(1));

    Column<ContactInfo, Boolean> firstNameColumn = new Column<ContactInfo, Boolean>(
            new NamedCheckBoxCell(true, false)) {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(ContactInfo object) {
            NamedCheckBoxCell namedCell = (NamedCheckBoxCell)this.getCell();
            namedCell.setTextValue(object.getLastName());
            // Get the value from the selection model.
            return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
        }
    };
    cellTable.addColumn(firstNameColumn, "Last Name");
    cellTable.setColumnWidth(firstNameColumn, 20, Unit.PCT);

    cellTable.addCellPreviewHandler(DefaultSelectionEventManager.<ContactInfo> createCheckboxManager(2));
    // Last name.
    Column<ContactInfo, Boolean> lastNameColumn = new Column<ContactInfo, Boolean>(
            new NamedCheckBoxCell(true, false)) {
        @Override
        public Boolean getValue(ContactInfo object) {
            NamedCheckBoxCell namedCell = (NamedCheckBoxCell)this.getCell();
            namedCell.setTextValue(object.getAddress());
            return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
        }
    };
    lastNameColumn.setSortable(true);
    cellTable.addColumn(lastNameColumn, "Address");
    cellTable.setColumnWidth(lastNameColumn, 20, Unit.PCT);
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please add snippet of your code, So people can elaborate you alternate way for solution.

Comment: Please i need solution as soon as possible if someone has any idea about how to handle or change checkbox selection events.